# I have total time and i want to minus from basic time

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one variable in which i have @totaltime of employee
and I have one variable in which Employee @basictime 
I want to get difference between in two variable
if @totaltime is less then @basictime answer will be negative, other wise show in positive

I use sql server 2008 r2
Can any one help me

Comment: I don't understand. Is it not just `select @totaltime - @basictime`?

Comment: Operand data type time is invalid for subtract operator     

Its error

Comment: What are the data types for your 2 variables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DATEDIFF`. The below example would give you the difference in seconds.

```
DECLARE @totaltime TIME
DECLARE @basictime TIME

SET @totaltime = '05:04:30'
SET @basictime = '10:45:31'

SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, @basictime, @totaltime)
```